# $refs.myChildComponent is undefined although I see it in the console

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In my child component I have two functions:

```
methods: {
  tutu: function () {
    ...
  },
  openMenu: function () {
    ...
  }
}
```

In my parent component, I'm trying to execute each of these functions in reaction to different events:

```
methods: {
  openMenu: function () {
    this.$refs.main_menu.openMenu();
  },
  handleResize: function () {
    this.$refs.main_menu.tutu();
  }
},
```

The first call (`this.$refs.main_menu.openMenu()`) works fine, but the second one fails with this error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'tutu' of undefined

In my parent component, `console.log(this.$refs)` shows both functions the same way. EDIT: `console.log(this.$refs.main_menu)` shows `undefined`.

I cannot understand why one of them works and not the other if everything is the same for both.

```
main_menu: VueComponent
...
openMenu: ƒ ()
arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:2:14)]
caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:2:14)]
length: 0
name: "bound openMenu"
...
tutu: ƒ ()
arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:2:14)]
caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:2:14)]
length: 0
name: "bound tutu"
__proto__: ƒ ()
```

Comment: Console logging of objects is live, so what you see when you expand is what's in the objects now, not necessarily what was there when it was logged. Try logging `this.$refs.main_menu` inside the functions of the parent component instead. As for why, that would depend on the timing of whatever calls them. `refs` are not available until the component is mounted.

Comment: You're right when I log `this.$refs.main_menu` I get `undefined`. About timing, there's no difference between the two functions, they are declared one after another in child component's `methods: {}`, and called by functions declared one after another in parent component 's `methods: {}`. This is incomprehensible...

Comment: Timing has nothing to do with the order they are declared. It is about when they are called. You haven't included that code in the question so it's difficult to be precise but it would appear that you're calling one of them before mounting and the other one after mounting. There are other possible explanations but we'd need to see the code calling them to try to identify the exact problem.

Comment: I was focused on declaration instead of where I call them from. The problematic call was made from `created()` hook so at a time where the component wasn't mounted yet, so you were spot on. You can make an answer that I'll accept if you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$refs` will only be populated after a component is mounted. So if you try to access a `ref` prior to that, for example from a `created` hook, it won't be there.

There are other ways that a `ref` can be missing. For example, if you're using `v-if` and the condition is `false`. In that case it isn't sufficient to wait for the condition to become `true`, you would also need to wait for a rendering update to be performed and such updates are queued. In that case you'd either need to use the `updated` hook or a call to `$nextTick`.